# Can i press two keys simultaneously for a single event using Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game using Pygame and Python.I wish to move a block by pressing two keys simultaneously.How can i do that? I am able to move the block  using a single key.. but it doesn't work for two keys together.

**I want the block to move wen i press "right key" and "1" together**

*The given code works efficiently move using a single key*

```
 if event.type==KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==K_RIGHT:
            move_fullcube=left
```

*I tried using "and" but it still doesn't work*

```
 if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_RIGHT and event.key==K_1:
                move_fullcube=left
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. This function returns a list of keys which are currently down. The following example shows how to check if two keys are being pressed at the same time:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    move_fullcube = left
```

See the documentation at https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different ways to do keyboard event handling in pygame. The first way is what you are doing, where you get a list of every event and loop through that list. The problem with your approach is that you can only look at a single event at a time, so `event.key` will never equal `K_RIGHT` *and* `K_1` at the same time because it's only a single key. Both events *will* happen, but you can only look at one of them at a time. If you want to do it this way, you must setup two variables `right_pressed` and `one_pressed`. Something like this

```
right_pressed = False
one_pressed = False
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==K_RIGHT:
            right_pressed = True
        if event.key==K_1:
            one_pressed = True
```

Then outside of your loop check if they are both true.

The other, easier way to do it is to use [pygame.keys.get_pressed()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed), which is much more convenient for checking if an individual key is down at the moment.