# How do I use pygame.key.get_pressed() to get one input?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to use pygame to perform an action when multiple keys are pressed at once, for example, when a and b are both pressed down, my program prints 'hi'. I tried pygame.KEYDOWN, but I couldn't find a way to detect multiple inputs with this. When I used pygame.key.get_pressed(), I got too many print statements as I only want one print statement, not a print statement as long as the key is pressed. Can someone help me with this issue?

Currently I have the following:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  # checking pressed keys
        if keys[pygame.K_r] and keys[pygame.K_l]:
            print('hi')
        elif keys[pygame.K_l]:
            print('bye')
```

But when I press r and l, hi is printed a lot of times but I only want it to print once.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126399/11666391).

Comment: I edited my post to make it more clear. The post works but it checks the key pressed for each event in pygame, but I only want the event to occur once when you press the buttons

Comment: using `get_pressed()` you would have to remeber `get_pressed()[pygame.K_r]` from previous loop - `previous_k = get_pressed()[pygame.K_r]` and print only when `previous_k` is `False` and current `get_pressed()[pygame.K_r]` is `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KEYDOWN` events hold a single key. To do what you want, you can combine the two methods.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.key == pygame.K_r and keys[pygame.K_l]:
            print("Hi")
        elif event.key == pygame.K_l:
            print('bye')
```

Basically, you catch the event from one of the two keys you want to have pressed together, and check if the other is pressed too.