# I have a function that detects if i press a key in pygame, but it only detects one key?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a function that detects key presses but, when i use the function and detect 'a' it detects but if i detect 'd' it doesnt detect it, but if i put the function that detects the key 'd' before the function that detects the key 'a' it detects 'd', why so?

here is my code:

```
keys = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','space','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
pygame_keys = [pygame.K_a,pygame.K_b,pygame.K_c,pygame.K_d,pygame.K_e,pygame.K_f,pygame.K_g,pygame.K_h,pygame.K_i,pygame.K_j,pygame.K_k,pygame.K_l,pygame.K_m,pygame.K_n,pygame.K_o,pygame.K_p,pygame.K_q,pygame.K_r,pygame.K_s,pygame.K_t,pygame.K_u,pygame.K_v,pygame.K_w,pygame.K_x,pygame.K_y,pygame.K_z,pygame.K_SPACE,pygame.K_1,pygame.K_2,pygame.K_3,pygame.K_4,pygame.K_5,pygame.K_6,pygame.K_7,pygame.K_8,pygame.K_9,pygame.K_0]


def key_pressed(key_press,one_click =False):
    global key_function_run 
    if one_click:
        key_function_run = True
    if not one_click:
        if kb.is_pressed(key_press):
            return True
    if one_click:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            for i in range(len(keys)):
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if key_press == keys[i]:
                        if event.key == pygame_keys[i]:
                            print(i)
                            return True
    pass
```

And here is how i am using the function:

```
    if x == 205:
        player_lane = 2
    if x == 60:
        player_lane = 1
    if x == 347:
        player_lane = 3
    #player movement
    if peasy.key_pressed('a',True) and player_lane == 2:
        x = 60
    if peasy.key_pressed('a',True) and player_lane == 3:
        x = 205
    if peasy.key_pressed('d',True) and player_lane == 2:
        x = 347
    if peasy.key_pressed('d',True) and player_lane == 1:
        x = 205
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can i press two keys simultaneously for a single event using Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121511/can-i-press-two-keys-simultaneously-for-a-single-event-using-pygame)

Comment: no, i need to use the pygame.KEYDOWN event. but thanks for trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dictionary from your lists:

```py
key_dict = dict(zip(keys, pygame_keys))
```

And use [`pygame.key.get_pressed`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html):

```py
def key_hold(keys, key):
    return keys[key_dict[key]]
```

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
is_a = key_hold(keys, 'a')
is_d = key_hold(keys, 'd')
```

---

If you want to use the `KEYDOWN` event, you have to be aware that [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. See the documentation:

> This will get all the messages and remove them from the queue. [...]

So you can call [`pygame.event.get`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) only once per frame. Also see [Faster version of 'pygame.event.get()'. Why are events being missed and why are the events delayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086113/faster-version-of-pygame-event-get-why-are-events-being-missed-and-why-are/58087070#58087070). However you can use `unicode` property of the `KEYDOWN` event:

```py
def key_down_event(event_list, c):
    return any(e for e in event_list if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.unicode == c)
```

```py
event_list = pygame.event.get()
is_a = key_down_event(event_list, 'a')
is_d = key_down_event(event_list, 'd')
```

---

If you want a function that detects both whether a key is held down or has been pressed, you need to count the frames of how long a key is pressed, for each key. Return `True` if the count for a key is 1 when you want to determine if the key was just pressed:

```py
import pygame

key_count = {}
def key_pressed(keys, key, one_click):
    pressed = keys[key]
    key_count[key] = (key_count.get(key, 0) + 1) if pressed else 0
    return key_count[key] == 1 if one_click else pressed
    
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    a_once = key_pressed(keys, pygame.K_a, True)
    d_hold = key_pressed(keys, pygame.K_d, False)
    if a_once:
        print(f'key event: {pygame.key.name(pygame.K_a)}')
    if d_hold:
        print(f'key pressed: {pygame.key.name(pygame.K_d)}')
    
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to make a custom function for input handling, you can use something like this:

```
running = True

def main():
    # Your normal game loop
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


        # Gets a list of the currently pressed keys,
        # this is updated because we put it in the while loop
        kbd = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if kbd[pygame.K_a]:
            print("I just pressed the A button!") # You can run here whatever ya want
```

Edit: I realized OP wanted to use `pygame.KEYDOWN` instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, so in that case, you can use something like this

```
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
           
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    print("Pressed D!")
```

Hope I helped. If you have any questions, just leave a comment/reply/whatever!

Comment: No. `kbd["A"]` does not work, because  the key needs to be `pygame.K_a`. => `kbd[pygame.K_a]`

Comment: Yeah, just corrected it. My bad!

Comment: i am trying to use pygame.KEYDOWN, because that returns if i click a button once, not when i click the button. which is what i need.

Comment: But the questioner wants to use "A", not `pygame.K_a`

Comment: acually im trying to write it as 'a' and then detect the a using pygame.K_a

Comment: this isn't very well documented, but you can use something like this https://pastebin.com/CFmqTXPC